# Codificação no Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, codificação-de-caracteres, ide

Estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho um web service em Java utilizando Jetty, o mesmo funciona normalmente caso eu faça requisição de outras aplicações para o servidor, porém os meus testes unitários estão retornando a codifição tudo errado.

```
{"message":"NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel criar o usuÃ¡rio. Error: E-mail jÃ¡ cadastrado.","status":"error"}
```

Eu estou utilizando a IDE Eclipse, e já tentei modificar em vários lugares, porém nenhum funciona:

Tentei em

```
File > Properties > Resource > Text File Encoding;

Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding

Botão direito no projeto > Preferences > Text File Encoding
```

O meu método que realiza a requisição é assim:

```
public static void executeMethod() throws IOException, HttpException {
        PostMethod post = createRequestPost(params, SIGNUP_ROTE);
        int status = HttpClient().executeMethod(aMethod);;
        String resultado = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você sabe qual codificação está sendo usada no texto de retorno do seu WebService?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode clicar com o botão direito no seu projeto e ir em *Properties*.

Na aba *Resource* tem o *group box* "*Text file encoding*".

Você pode mudar pra [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) aí pra usar caracteres especiais.

**Edição:**
[utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) permite que você use caracteres especiais mesmo. Tipo ☺ e coisas do gênero.

O [iso-8859-1](/questions/tagged/iso-8859-1) permite você usar acentos e cedilha. ;)